# How to add a modified part of a Video back to it's source?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, crop

I have cropped a certain section of the video(let's say with dim 200x200) as 60x60 from coordinates (20,30). Now I have edited the cropped version of the video.

My question is how to paste that edited portion of video back to the original video(200x200) using `ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 0):

Basic syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i original -i cropped -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=x=20:y=30" -c:a copy out
```

This assumes you haven't reduced or increased the duration of the edited portion.